# Возвращает количество корзин с фруктами

Tags: python

```
def fruit_order(small_baskets: int, big_baskets: int, ordered_amount: int) -> int:
"""
Вернуть количество маленьких корзин, если это возможно для завершения заказа. Если это невозможно, то вернуть -1 

(4, 1, 9) -> 4
(3, 1, 10) -> -1
"""
pass
```

Большая корзина фруктов включает в себя 5 кг, маленькая 1 кг. Как я понимаю необходимо использовать алгоритм с началом if ordered_amount % 5:
Дальше исходя из остатка необходимо посчитать сколько маленьких корзин получится(result) и если их количество совпадает со small_baskets, то return result. Если нет, то return -1

```
if small_baskets == result:
return result
if small_baskets != result:
return -1
```

Понимаю вроде принцип и условия задачи, а записать алгоритм с остатком не могу. Хотелось бы получить вашей помощи в написании кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наполняем по максимуму большие корзины, потом проверяем, что в маленькие поместится то, что осталось

```
def fruit_order(small_baskets: int, big_baskets: int, ordered_amount: int) -> int:
    """
    Вернуть количество маленьких корзин, если это возможно для завершения заказа. 
    Если это невозможно, то вернуть -1

    (4, 1, 9) -> 4
    (3, 1, 10) -> -1
    """
    if big_baskets:
        big = min(ordered_amount // big_baskets, big_baskets)
        ordered_amount -= 5 * big
    if ordered_amount > small_baskets:
        return -1
    return ordered_amount
```

Comment: может можете ещё подсказать, возникла ошибка с делением на 0. Мне казалось, что была какая-то возможность этого избежать. Можете подсказать?

Comment: Поправил код. пробуйте